# How can I perform sorting ORDER BY expression in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

```
select p.Id, sum(inc.Quantity) 
from Products p join Incomes inc
group by p.Id 
order by sum(inc.Quantity) >0
```

This query gives NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QuerySyntaxException on ORDER BY clause. I wonder is it possible to overcome this error and perform sorting by some expression?

**UPDATE**
I need to sort products list by name, price etc. *BUT* products with quantity == 0 must go to the bottom of the list (no matter what name, price it has). Also I need to perform paging of that list.

Comment: Do you have multiple entries with the same Id? That would be an odd sort of Id... but if you don't, why are you grouping by that?

Comment: I have JOIN in my query - so in result set I have multiple rows with the same Id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a syntax that is supported by SQL too. This works:

```
select p.Id, sum(inc.Quantity) 
from Products p join p.Incomes inc
group by p.Id 
order by case when sum(inc.Quantity) > 0 then 0 else 1 end
```

*Nitpicking: why do your entities have plural names?*

Answer (score 0):

It's a while since I've done any NHibernate, but I'd have expected you to *at least* want to remove the `> 0` bit of the ordering:

```
order by sum(inc.Quantity)
```

or possibly use an alias:

```
select p.Id, sum(inc.Quantity) totalQuantity
from Products p join Incomes inc
group by p.Id 
order by totalQuantity
```

I don't know if that'll work, but it's worth a shot :)

Comment: I don't want to remove "> 0" part beacause I want to perform sorting by THAT boolean flag (product is available - products total quantity > 0). I've also tried using aliases - they don't work

Comment: @kilonet: Surely if you sort by the normal quantity that *will* effectively sort by whether or not the product is in stock: 0 will come before any positive values.

Comment: still, when sorting by sum (unlike boolean expression) I can't perform additional sorting by price or by name for example

Comment: @kilonet: In this case you can't sort by price or by name because those aren't aggregates - it's more to do with the *grouping* than anything else. If you could give detail of what you're really trying to do, that would help.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select p.Id, sum(inc.Quantity) 
from Products p join Incomes inc
group by p.Id 
having sum(inc.Quantity) > 0
order by sum(inc.Quantity)
```

Order by is used for sorting. To filter on aggregated fields use having.

See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-grouping